# gcc - removing "is used uninitialized in this function" warning

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

Cleaning code from warning after adding -O2 -Wall flags to gcc (4.4.6).
I have a lot of warning in some legacy code. This is very simplified version to demonstrate the problem:

```
 1 #include <cstdio>
  2
  3 bool init(bool& a)
  4 {
  5     return true;
  6 }
  7
  8 int main()
  9 {
 10     bool a;
 11
 12     if (!init(a))
 13     {
 14         return 1;
 15     }
 16
 17     if (a)
 18     {
 19         printf("ok\n");
 20     }
 21 }
```

When compiling it as "gcc main.cpp -O2 -Wall" I receive:

```
 main.cpp:17: warning: `a' is used uninitialized in this function
```

In real code, init() returns true only if it initializes "a", so there's virually no use by uninitialized "a".

Whan can be done to fix the warning.

Comment: You want to compile code that generates undefined behaviour, yet you are using `-Wall`? Will you come back to SO later on when you want to figure out why your UB programs don't work?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

change `bool a;` to `bool a = false;` will remove this warning.

The compiler wont know `init(a)` is meant to 'initialize a', it only sees the program tries to call a function with a uninitialized variable.

Comment: But `init()` never writes anything into its argument, so the compiler is correct, no initialization ever ocurred.

Answer (score 13):

If you don't want to initialize the variable with some value, you can use GCC's [diagnostic pragmas](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html):

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wuninitialized"
   if( a )
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

This might be handy if your code has performace issues when everything would be initialized. In your example, of course, using `bool a = false;` is clearly the better choice.

Comment: Likely, the second push is supposed to be a pop. I believe the first push is unnecessary.

Comment: @jxh Thanks, fixed the answer for the pop. The push OTOH is necessary as a pop without a push would simply restore the options from the command line. If someone wants to nest another push/pop around the above (for larger context), I would pop whatever the other developer pushed and that would create chaos. It's therefore best practice to always have matching local push/pop-pairs.

Comment: Here's a case where uninitialized values could be useful, if they were implemented suitably in the compiler: I use _mm_set_epi64(dontcare,x ) to convert a m64 vector to m128, where dontcare is unintialized, and I really don't care what it is, since the value is used in a _mm_unpacklo_ downstream. If I place a specific value in the 'dontcare' I may imply extra code to generate it. It's unlikely (tho possible) the compiler knows that this value is a don't care from the operators, and can drop that code.  But, if I don't init the don't-care, the whole thing could get dropped by the optimizer. :-(

Comment: What's really needed here is an intrinsic `_mm_dontcare_si64()` which is seen as a valid value for the semantics, but is treated as a don't-care in the code generator and optimizer.

Answer (score 6):

```
int main()
{
    bool a = false;
    ...
```

**Initialize all variables, always!**

Comment: I disagree. Initializing things that *shouldn't* need to be initialized can lead to bugs being hidden. This could be a long rant, but I'll leave it at this example here, for the special case of local variables: suppose you define a local that *will* be set in one branch or the other of some 'if' structure below. Leaving it uninitialized at the decl. means you'll get a warning if you failed to set it in all the branches. Initializing it to 0 (as a general practice, w/o thinking) will suppress that warning, so the compiler will no longer help you know (by lack of warning) that it's always set.

Answer (score 2):

add -Wno-uninitialized to your compile option

Comment: -1. Disabling compile warnings which - in this case - show the programmer that there's an actual problem in the code (in this case, caused by undefined behaviour) is definitely not a good practice.

Comment: this is a answer as to how to suppress that warning, not to good practice.